# Proving that an equation has only a fixed point

Tags: metric-spaces, fixed-point-theorems, fixed-points

I only need a hint to solve this problem:
Show that the equation $x^4+8x^3+32x-32=0$ has only a fixed point at the interval $[0,1]$.
I know that as $\mathbb{R}$ is complete with the usual metric and $[0,1]$ is a closed subset then it's complete too, so now I only have to prove that the equation is a contraction so that by a theorem then the equation will have only a fixed point.
My question is: how do I prove that an equation is a contraction? I only know the definition of contraction for functions. Should I write $f(x)=x^4+8x^3+32x-32$? If it's so explain why, please.

Comment: Equations don't have fixed points, functions (or maybe functors) do.

Comment: If you want to prove that $|f(x)-f(y)|<|x-y|$ that's the same as proving $\left\lvert\frac{f(x)-f(y)}{x-y}\right\rvert<1$. Does the mean value theorem work?

Comment: I guessed so but that way is written in the book that the teacher gave us to make the homework. I have a trouble with that. Can you think of what he's meaning?

Comment: @saulspatz  I know about applying mean value theorem. What I don't get is what's the book meaning with the fixed point of an equation.

Comment: A fixed point of a function (not an equation) $f$ is a value $x$ such that $f(x)=x$.

Comment: Iesus, you are mistaken setting the quartic to zero. Suggest you simply draw (by hand) a graph of the quartic, and see approximately where it crosses the line $y=x.$

Comment: @saulspatz. Yes I know that, but as I mentioned above I don't know why the problem says the fixed point of an equation. That's my doubt

Comment: @Will, what's the purpose on doing that? (It's only a doubt)

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand what you said, although now that I know, I see you expressed it quite clearly.  I think it's an error, and  the author meant to say a fixed point of the function $f$.  I don't think I've ever heard the term "fixed point of an equation."

Comment: Iesus, if you draw the graphs, you will understand the point.

Comment: @Will, oh, I see, I have understood your point. Thank you so much.

Comment: But drawing the quartic is to assume that we work with $f(x)$, right? That is, I better write it as a function and not as an equation which is what I wrote at the beginning